# Scale X software

Tags: xorg, xdmcp, scale

I have a X software which only runs at 640x480. Now I have a Xvnc with XDMCP that runs on 320x240, and this result the software being "cropped" so only a 1/4th of the software is visible. Now I would want to "scale" the software by 50 % by some wrapper. How can this be achieved?

In other words, any software run through the wrapper should be shrinked or enlarged according to a option.

Comment: What about just making the Xvnc window bigger? This way, you could end up with an actually readable output.

Comment: It gets very slow then. Since the network between client and server is slow.

Comment: Try to solve the speed problem - even 640x480 is very small. Even if it were possible to scale the stream down to 1/4 the size on the VNC server side (X client side) you're not going to a significant benefit compared over running it natively at 320x240. What bit-depth are you using?

Comment: symcbean: The software does not support running 320x240 natively. So I could scale down the software, and then run the software on a 320x240 screen. Thats what im asking for. In other words, I need something like a negative magnifying glass software.

Comment: Im have tried to lower bit depth, but that introduces "dithering" (dots in different colors) and making it veeeery sloooow because it kills the JPEG compression.

Answer (score 0):

If speed is a problem, maybe you could solve your problem with [NX](http://nomachine.com/). It's highly optimized to work over slow networks with high latency. I've successfully used it with a 1024x768 desktop over an ISDN line.

Edit:

If NX does't work, maybe you can [speed things up with the help of RDP](http://www.css-networks.com/2010/12/linuxunix-x-as-an-rdp-remote-desktop-protocol-server/), which is also much more efficient than VNC. I haven't tested this, though.

Comment: The problem is that NX is not well suited for being used in situations where untrusted users will have access to the NX server. The NX has too many options on the client side. The whole thing is supposed to run without authentication, and in a "kiosk" setting (tightly locked down desktop) where anyone on internet can access this public server. So Xvnc is the only thing that works.

Comment: @Sebastian nielsen: See my edit, maybe this helps.

Comment: SvenW: It does not seem to support XDMCP. Thats required for the whole thing to be multisession (eg support multiple users connected at the same time). What the server does when a client connects, is autologging in the user "kiosk" with a simple X window manager that kicks off a second software. This "second software" does only support 640x480, thats why I need something to shrink (scale) the window to 320x240. So in other words, I simply share the software in a "cloud" fashion.